# Give an example of a function that satisfy $\int_a^bf'(x)dx < f(b)-f(a)$ in Lebesgue's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

According to Lebesgue's theorem on differentiation,  if $f$ is an increasing function on a closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$, then $f'$ exist and is measurable and $$\int_a^bf'(x)dx \le f(b)-f(a)$$. 
Can someone give me an example of a function for which strict inequality occur in this case?

Comment: Is the right side correct as it is? If so that's $0.$ I would guess $f(b)-f(a)$ for it, as in usual calc that would be equality.

Comment: Sorry , that was a mistake

Comment: The correct statement is $f'(x)$ exists for a.e. $x.$

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x)$ to be a step function, say $f(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=1$ otherwise. On $[-1,1]$, you get $0\leq 1$.

Comment: Here $f'$ fails to exist at $0.$ (Or maybe Lebesgue only says diff a.e.)

Comment: So in this case $f'(x)=0$ and $$\int_{-1}^{1}f'(x)dx=\int_{-1}^00dx+\int_0^10dx=0+0=0$$ whiles $$f(1)=1 $$ since $1\in [0,1]$  from the definition of $f$ and$$f(-1)=0$$ since $0\in [-1,0)$. so $f(1)-f(-1)=1-0=0$. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @coffeemath: if $f(x)$ is differentiable *everywhere*, then the second fundamental theorem of calculus guarantees equality. Whereas, a monotonically increasing function is guaranteed only to be differentiable almost everywhere.

Comment: @AlexR. Yes I read a proof of that a.e. statement for monotone functions once. I was reacting to OP's quote after "According to..." which has in it "then $f'$ exists and..."

Comment: @Coffeemath: Yes you are right. it is almost everywhere